# Redshift Usage - 1 row by 400 columns per user or (20-400) rows by 4 columns per user

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-redshift, nosql

We are building an analytics engine which has to store attribute preference score for each user. We are expecting 400 attributes and they may change(at what frequency is not known as yet). We are planning to store this in Redshift.

My qs is:

1. Should we store as 1 row per user with 400 cols(1 column for each attribute)
   or should we go for a table structure like 
   (uid, attribute id, attribute value, preference score)  which will be (20-400)rows by 3 columns
   Which kind of storage would lead to a better performance in Redshift.
2. Should be really consider NoSQL for this?

Note: 
1. This is a backend for real time application with increasing number of users.
2. For processing, the above table has to be read with entire information of all attibutes for one user i.e indirectly create a 1*400 matrix at runtime.

Please help me which desgin would be ideal for such a use case. Thank you

Comment: I don't know about redshift, but in common sql database it's better to have more smaller tables then one huge table. It will be better to create more smaller logical tables. Like address, personal information etc.

Comment: But one table should have more columns or more rows..Which design is better to be read faster?

Comment: From my experience with oracleSql I had long time to load with more rows when count of rows was over > 100 000. On the other side so much columns are problems when you try something like this `select * from tbl`. Or you want to insert or update table. On more rows in your design there also be problem with readability of your data.

Comment: Sorry, I could not get your point. could you please elaborate?

Comment: Ok, I'll try: High number of rows: `select * from tbl` takes minutes if you have > 100 000 rows. Readability of data is much more lower. For every user for example you have uid, attribute id, attribute value, preference score on 400 rows. When you try to work with this data it will be really hard. High number of columns: This means bad database design. Every insert or update in this table will be slow and `select * from tbl` will be also slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for tables like given in this example and then use bitwise functions

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_bitwise_examples.html

Bitwise functions are [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_bitwise_aggregate_functions.html)

Comment: This solution is interesting. But I have a table with a score i.e between 0 and 1. 
Eg. a row for every user with columns for each attribute value as 0.5
and like this I can have 400 columns for each user. How could that be stored using this?

Comment: You need to store flag 1 or 0 for each column. then group 63 to 64 columns together to create on column. That will create binary like 1001010101010... store it in one column and so on....

Comment: But my scores are not 0 or 1..it is a number between 0 and 1. How do we do that? eg. 0.5, 0.66,0.65

Comment: this suits more if you have 0 or 1 (binary) ,for others you need some other solutions

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, I would suggest a two table design. Its more pain in the beginning but will help in future.

First table would be a key value kind of first table, which would store all the base data and would be kind of future proof, where you can add/remove more attributes, but this table will continue working.

And a N(400 in your case) column 2nd table. This second table you can build using the first table. For the second table, you can start with a bare minimum set of columns .. lets say only 50 out of those 400. So that querying this table would be really fast. And the structure of this table can be refreshed periodically to match with the current reporting requirements. Also you will always have the base table in case you need to backfill any data.